# BMR calculator in a class component react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
    import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
    
    export class Register extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          In: "",
          lbs: "",
          age: "",
          gender: "",
    
        };
      }
    
    render() {
    
        //BMR Calculator
        const { In } = this.state;
        const { lbs } = this.state;
        const { age } = this.state;
        const { gender } = this.state;
    
    return (
          <SafeAreaView>
                <View>
                  <TextInput
                    label="username"
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                  />
    
                  <TextInput
                    label="email"
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                  />
    
                  <TextInput                    
                    label="password"
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                  />
                </View>
  
                    <Text>Weight</Text>

                      <TextInput
                        placeholder="In"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        maxLength="2"
                        onChangeText={(In) => this.setState({ In })}
                        style={styles.heightImperialIn}
                      />

                   <Text>Weight</Text>

                     <TextInput
                      placeholder="lbs"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      maxLength="3"
                      value={lbs}
                      onChangeText={(lbs) => this.setState(+e.target.value)}
                      //onChangeText={(lbs) => this.setState({ lbs })}
                      style={styles.weigthImperial}
                     />

                   <Text style={styles.txtAge}>Age</Text>

                    <TextInput
                      placeholder="18"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      maxLength="2"
                      value={age}
                      onChange={(age) => this.setState(+e.target.value)}
                      //onChangeText={(age) => this.setState({ age })}
                      style={styles.ageImperial}
                    />

                   <Text>Gender</Text>

                    <View style={{ top: hp("10%") }}>
                      <RNPickerSelect
                        style={pickerStyle}
                        placeholder={{
                          label: "Select a gender",
                          value: null,
                        }}
                        onValueChange={(gender) => this.setState({ gender })}
                        items={[
                          { label: "Male", value: "male" },
                          { label: "Female", value: "female" },
                        ]}
                      />
                    </View>
             </SafeAreaView>
```

Hey, everyone, so I have these two equations for a BMR calculator :

1. male=66+(6.2*lbs)+(12.7*In)-(6.76*age)
2. female=655.1+(4.35*lbs)+(4.7*In)-(4.7*age)

My question is how do I get the values of `lbs`, `In` and `age` from the text inputs above and inserted them in one of the two equations, depending on the gender selected by the user, and display the result?

Thanks

Comment: could you add the live example ? use codesandbox for the same

Comment: I might understand it even if you could just show me an example of how you can add two values from text inputs in a class component and show the result on the same page, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: you have the values updated in `state` , use them to do arithmetic op

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BMR calculator React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592312/bmr-calculator-react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/bmr-app)

[image]

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      In: 0,
      lbs: 0,
      age: 0,
      gender: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    //BMR Calculator
    const { In, lbs, age, gender } = this.state;

    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            label="username"
            onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
          />

          <TextInput
            label="email"
            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
          />

          <TextInput
            label="password"
            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
          />
        </View>

        <Text>Weight</Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="In"
          keyboardType="numeric"
          maxLength="2"
          onChangeText={(In) => this.setState({ In: Number(In) })}
          style={styles.heightImperialIn}
        />

        <Text>Weight</Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="lbs"
          keyboardType="numeric"
          maxLength="3"
          value={lbs}
          onChangeText={(lbs) => {
            console.log(typeof Number(lbs));
            this.setState({ lbs: Number(lbs) });
          }}
        />

        <Text style={styles.txtAge}>Age</Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="18"
          keyboardType="numeric"
          maxLength="2"
          onChangeText={(age) => this.setState({ age: Number(age) })}
          style={styles.heightImperialIn}
        />

        <Text>Gender</Text>

        <View style={{}}>
          <RNPickerSelect
            style={{}}
            placeholder={{
              label: 'Select a gender',
              value: null,
            }}
            onValueChange={(gender) => this.setState({ gender })}
            items={[
              { label: 'Male', value: 'male' },
              { label: 'Female', value: 'female' },
            ]}
          />
        </View>

        <Text>Result for {gender.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        {gender ? (
          gender === 'male' ? (
            66 + 6.2 * lbs + 12.7 * In + 6.76 * age
          ).toFixed(2) : (
            65.51 + 4.35 * lbs + 4.7 * In - 4.7 * age
          ).toFixed(2)
        ) : (
          <Text>Select the values</Text>
        )}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});
```

Comment: Dude, you are the best

Comment: Glad it helped, Welcome and hapy coding.